# All of my data points are lost when InfluxDB restarts

Tags: java, influxdb

A cron job is being used to fire this script off once a day. When the script runs it seems to work as expected. The code builds a map, iterates over that map, creates points which are added to a batch, and finally writes those batched points to influxDB.  I can connect to the influxDB and I can query my database and see that the points were added. I am using **[influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) 2.2**.

The issue that I am having is that when influxDB is restarted all of my data is being removed. The database still exists and the series still exists, however, all of the points/rows are gone (Each table is empty). My database is not the only database, there are several others, those databases are restored correctly. My guess is that the transaction is not being finalized. I am not aware of a way to make it do a flush and ensure that my points are persisted. I tried to adding:

```
influxDB.write(batchPoints);
influxDB.disableBatch();  // calls this.batchProcessor.flush() in InfluxDBImpl.java
```

This was an attempt to force a flush but this didn't work as expected. I am using **influxDB 0.13.X**

```
    InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(host, user, pass);

    String dbName = "dataName";
    influxDB.createDatabase(dbName);

    BatchPoints batchPoints = BatchPoints
            .database(dbName)
            .tag("async", "true")
            .retentionPolicy("default")
            .consistency(ConsistencyLevel.ALL)
            .build();

    for (Tags type: Tags.values()) {
        List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> myList = this.trendsMap.get(type.getDisplay());

        if (myList != null) {
            for (LinkedHashMap<String, Object> data : myList) {
                Point point = null;
                long time = (long) data.get("time");
                if (data.get("date").equals(this.sdf.format(new Date()))) { 
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }

                point = Point.measurement(type.getDisplay())
                .time(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .field("count", data.get("count"))
                .field("date", data.get("date"))
                .field("day_of_week", data.get("day_of_week"))
                .field("day_of_month", data.get("day_of_month"))
                .build();

                batchPoints.point(point);
            }
        }
    }

    influxDB.write(batchPoints);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade InfluxDB to 0.11.0? There have been many important changes since then and it would be best to test against that.

Comment: This got put on a back burner but is now back in the spotlight. I am currently using influxDB version 0.13.0  and now using influxdb-java 2.2.